# Installing Xdebug in docker for PHP 7.4

Tags: docker, phpunit, php-7.4

I'm attempting to setup unit tests and test coverage for a PHP 7.4 project using PHPUnit 9.x. I've been able to get it working locally, but I'm having a difficult time getting it running in a pipeline runner on GitLab, which is just using Docker under the hood. I'm using the `php:7.4` image. At this point, the tests are running, but a coverage report is skipped with the warning:

> No code coverage driver available

I've been trying to get Xdebug 3.1.5 installed, as it's the latest version that supports PHP 7.4. From a number of other threads on Stack Overflow and other sites, it appears that most people are suggesting running these two commands:

```bash
pecl install xdebug-3.1.5
docker-php-ext-install xdebug
```

When these are run, the second one errors out with

> /usr/src/php/ext/xdebug does not exist

Running `docker-php-ext-install xdebug-3.1.5` gives the same kind of error. I've also tried skipping the second command altogether, but I still get the warning from phpunit about no coverage driver.

How might I go about getting `xdebug-3.1.5` installed so I can get a coverage report from PHPUnit?

Comment: `docker-php-ext-enable xdebug`* and not `docker-php-ext-install`, it is actually in the documentation: https://hub.docker.com/_/php under the _"PECL extensions"_ chapter.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε `docker-php-ext-enable xdebug` did the trick. Thanks! Feel free to share it as an answer so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the name points out the command `docker-php-ext-install` is meant to install a PHP extension – an `.so` file. Using PECL is just another way of installing extensions, so, by trying to use `docker-php-ext-install` after a `pecl install` you are trying to do twice the same thing.

And as the end of the `pecl install` points out:

> You should add "zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so" to php.ini

Which would be what [`docker-php-ext-enable`](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/5bfc95d4880599cf9e85f5b5f99940cf123ebcf0/docker-php-ext-enable) is meant to do.

So, your working *Dockerfile* would be:

```bash
FROM php:7.4

RUN pecl install xdebug-3.1.5 \
      && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

---

This is actually pointed out in the documentation of the `php` image:

> ##### PECL extensions
>
> Some extensions are not provided with the PHP source, but are instead available through [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/). To install a PECL extension, use `pecl install` to download and compile it, then use `docker-php-ext-enable` to enable it:
>
> ```bash
> FROM php:7.4-cli
> RUN pecl install redis-5.1.1 \
>       && pecl install xdebug-2.8.1 \
>       && docker-php-ext-enable redis xdebug
> ```

*<sup>Source: https://hub.docker.com/_/php</sup>*